# Providing Providers to Dynamic NestJS Modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, nest

How Can I use `export const { ConfigurableModuleClass, MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN } = new ConfigurableModuleBuilder<ConfigModuleOptions>().setFactoryMethodName('createConfigOptions').build();` to provide multiple providers to a dynamic module?

I read this article [Providing Providers to Dynamic NestJS Modules](https://dev.to/nestjs/providing-providers-to-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1i6n). It is just using a thirty party library. I believe since it was published two years ago the `ConfigurableModuleBuilder` can achieve this same use case.

So How can I divide the options passed into `registerAsync` into several providers?

```
    AuthModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [UserModule],
      inject: [UserService, ConfigService],
      useFactory: (userService: UserService, configService: ConfigService) => ({
        userService: userService,
        configService
      }),
    }),
```

So, for the code snnipet above how can I do the below?

```
    @Inject(USER_SERVICE) private userService: IUserService,
    @Inject(CONFIG_SERVICE) private configService: IConfigService,
```

Module Definition file

```
export const {
  ConfigurableModuleClass,
  MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN,
  OPTIONS_TYPE,
  ASYNC_OPTIONS_TYPE,
} = new ConfigurableModuleBuilder<AuthModuleOptions>().build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can be done here is you can make the `AuthModule` have a `@Module()` decorator that looks like the following:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: USER_SERVICE,
      inject: [MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN],
      useFactory: (options: AuthModuleOptions) => options.userService
    },
    {
      provide: CONFIG_SERVICE,
      inject: [MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN],
      useFactory: (options: AuthModuleOptions) => options.configService,
    }
  ],
})
export class AuthModules extends ConfigurableModuleClass {}
```

Do note that doing this will allow other services *within* the `AuthModule` to inject the userServicevia `@Inject(USER_SERVICE)`, but it also means that `AuthModule` will **not** be usable without using the `forRoot`/`forRootAsync` methods.

[I have a working example with my `OgmaModule` here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/main/packages/nestjs-module/src/ogma-core.module.ts)